# Creating multidimensional shifting array using a vectorize approach instead of FOR loop

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vectorization, octave

I can "Vectorize" the circshift command but I'm having trouble adding dimensions to it.

See code below with **working FOR loop** that I'm trying to vectorize using dimensions

```
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc , close all

function  [outMat] =  vectcircshift(vectToShift,shiftVector)
%This function generates a matrix where each row is a circshift of the
%original vector from the specified interval in the shiftVector;
%
%Inputs
%vectToShift:   is the original vector you want to circshift multiple times
%shiftVector:   is the vector of the circshift sizes;
%
%Outputs
%outMat:        is a matrix were every row is circshift by the amount in the
%               shiftVector
  [n,m]=size(vectToShift);
  if n>m
    inds=(1:n)';
    i=toeplitz(flipud(inds),circshift(inds,[1 0]));
    outMat=vectToShift(i(shiftVector,:));
    outMat=circshift(outMat,[0,-1]); %shift to include original signal first
  else
    inds=1:m;
    i=toeplitz(fliplr(inds),circshift(inds,[0 1]));
    outMat=vectToShift(i(shiftVector,:));
    outMat=circshift(outMat,[0,-1]); %shift to include original signal first
  end
end

%%----Working FOR LOOP below I'm trying to vectorize.
ndim=0;
ndim_tot=[1:3] %total dimensions
for ndim=1:length(ndim_tot)
  ndim=ndim+0
  if ndim==1
      array_sort(ndim,:)=circshift(ndim_tot,[0 ndim-1]) %start at row of sort array
  else
      array_sort(ndim,:)=circshift(ndim_tot,[0 mod(-ndim,length(ndim_tot))+1]) %next start of row of sort array

  endif
  array_sort= array_sort(ndim,:)
  array_dim(:,:,ndim)=vectcircshift([1:5],array_sort)
endfor
```

I tired the syntax below but that logic won't work.

```
ndim_tot=[1:3]; %number of dimensions
array_dim2(:,:,ndim_tot)=vectcircshift([1:5],[1:3])
```

I get an error nonconformant arguments(op1 is 0x0x1, op2 is 3x5)

My goal is to create a multidimensional array that circshifts a signal / array and also creates and shifts it in multiple dimensions.

```
Example: of what the multidimensional array would look like
if I start with a signal / array a1=[1 2 3 4 5]

I'm trying to have it create.

array_dim(:,:,1)=
[
1 2 3 4 5
5 1 2 3 4
4 5 1 2 3
]

array_dim(:,:,2)=
[
5 1 2 3 4
4 5 1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5
]

array_dim(:,:,3)=
[
4 5 1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5
5 1 2 3 4
]
```

**Please note:  the the numbers won't be sequential I just used it as an example to help explain things a little easier.**

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2

Comment: Trying to understand your solution, but I am struggling with `array_sort(ndim,:)=...` `array_sort= array_sort(ndim,:)`. Can't you directly assign to `array_sort`?

Comment: @Daniel I tried directly assigning it but the rows of the `array_sort` weren't in the correct order to be placed in the multidimensional array, hence I had to add a IF / Then statement to the FOR loop to fix it.   If you see a direct way to assign it let  me know this could help get rid of the FOR loop.   The `array_sort` variable controls how the rows are placed in the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear why you are shifting in mod 3, but here is a loop assignment using shift

```
a1=[1 2 3 4 5];
array_dim=zeros(3,5,3);

for i=0:2
        array_dim(:,:,i+1)=[shift(a1,i);
                shift(a1,mod(i+1,3));
                shift(a1,mod(i+2,3))];
endfor

array_dim
```

and the output fits your example

```
array_dim =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   3   4   5
   5   1   2   3   4
   4   5   1   2   3

ans(:,:,2) =

   5   1   2   3   4
   4   5   1   2   3
   1   2   3   4   5

ans(:,:,3) =

   4   5   1   2   3
   1   2   3   4   5
   5   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: Thanks for the FOR loop but in my title `Creating multidimensional shifting array using a vectorize approach instead of FOR loop'  I even included a working FOR loop` with code in my question the goal is to `vectorize` it.  see the code above with the FOR loop I'm trying to vectorize the title is `%%----Working FOR LOOP below I'm trying to vectorize.`

Comment: what is not clear from your foggy code is what is the rule you are applying for the shifts. Assuming `array_dim` as A,B,C dimensions, how are you shifting your original A1 for every 1st and 3rd index ? It seems the B dimension is the same between the original data.

Comment: yes my code is very foggy (that's a nice way of saying convoluted) :-)  yours is much better by far.  Is it possible to vectorize your FOR loop it does what I'm looking for.